# How to set up a beautiful url in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel

Now my url looks like this

```
localhost/3
```

But I want the path to look like this

```
localhost/some-text
```

To do this, I have a special url field in the Ad model, where the desired address is located. But going through it, I get 404

I have a route

```
Route::get('/{url}', [App\Http\Controllers\IndexController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
```

Method

```
public function show($url) {
    $ad = Ad::where('url', $url)->first();
    return view('ad', compact('ad'));
}
```

And btn

```
<a href="{{ route('show', ['url' => $ad->url]) }}">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
</a>
```

Comment: its called slug..

Comment: The `404` a `page not found` error. Are you certain your `routes` are correct?

Answer (score 0):

To create better links just use slug

[I use laravel slugable](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable)